# How do I automatically pass arguments to a function on certain objects

Tags: python

I am trying to make a text based game using Python. I set up a radar() function but currently the only way to use it is if the player types in arguments directly to the console. I want the program to detect which vehicle the player is piloting and pass whatever attributes of that vehicle need to be passed automatically without the player having to type them.

For example
Instead of the player having to type in 
'a.radar([100,100,100], 100)' in order to use the radar() function I want the player to only need to type in 'radar', and all other parameters to be passed automatically. How can I make this happen? Should I restructure this code entirely?

My code:

```
class Mobilesuits:
    #class global variables/methods here
    instances = [] #grid cords here
    def __init__(self,armor,speed,name,description,cockpit_description,\
                 radar_range, coordinates):
        Mobilesuits.instances.append(self)
        self.armor=armor
        self.speed=speed
        self.name=name
        self.description=description
        self.cockpit_description=cockpit_description
        self.radar_range=radar_range
        self.coordinates=coordinates


    def radar(self, coordinates, radar_range):
        for i in range(len(a.instances)):
            cordcheck=a.instances[i].coordinates
            if cordcheck == coordinates:
                pass
            elif (abs(cordcheck[0]-coordinates[0]) <= radar_range) and \
                (abs(cordcheck[1]-coordinates[1]) <= radar_range) and \
                (abs(cordcheck[2]-coordinates[2]) <= radar_range):
                print("%s detected at %s ") %(a.instances[i].description, a.instances[i].coordinates)



a=Mobilesuits(100,100,"Leo","leo desc","dockpit desc",100,[100,100,100])
b=Mobilesuits(100,100,"Leo","leo desc","dockpit desc",100,[300,100,100])
c=Mobilesuits(100,100,"Leo","leo desc","dockpit desc",100,[100,150,100])

a.radar([100,100,100], 100)
```

Comment: `print("%s detected at %s ") %(a.instances[i].description, a.instances[i].coordinates)` - you're on Python 2. Don't put parentheses around the string you're passing to `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your program take input with the `raw_input` function:

```
user_input = raw_input()
```

and then do something based on the input:

```
if user_input == "some_command":
    do_something(appropriate, variables)
```

For example,

```
if user_input == "radar":
    a.radar([100,100,100], 100)
```

You might also want to change the way the `radar` method takes arguments. It looks like at least one of the `coordinates` or the `radar_range` arguments should be coming from the corresponding attributes of `self`. For example, if a mobile suit's radar should automatically use the mobile suit's own coordinates and radar range, you could write the method as follows:

```
def can_detect(self, other):
    for own_coord, other_coord in zip(self.coordinates, other.coordinates):
        if abs(own_coord - other_coord) > self.radar_range:
            return False
    return True

def radar(self):
    for other in Mobilesuits.instances:
        if other is not self and self.can_detect(other):
            print "%s detected at %s" % (other.description, other.coordinates)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I learned a lot from your input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like builtins do.

Look, `str()` function is just specialized call to `__str__` function. `object` class has default `__str__`, and if you're not using p3k, `str()` has some logic for objects without `__str__`.

In the end, `str()` builtin MAY look like this (conceptually, implementation is probably quite different):

```
def str(obj):
    try:
         return obj.__str__()
    except AttributeError:
         return default_behaviour(obj)
```

You can do something alike.

You'll need function which will return user object (say there are 3 players in the game: A, B and C, where A is controlled by user; you'll need function `get_user_player()` which shall return A instance.

Then, you need to implement your argumentless `radar` function:

```
def radar():
    return get_user_player().radar()
```

Now call to `radar()` will result in automatic finding of user controlled instance and calling radar on it.